# Charfield not showing up in django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am creating a basic django site that uses django-userena. I am overriding the default signup form by creating a EditProfileFormExtra class on my forms.py. However, I am finding a very strange problem. The fields "latitude" and "longitude" do not show up. Changing the name of the fields seems to make them show up, but naming them "lat" or "latitude" and "long" or "longitude" makes them dissappear ?! Why is this?

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from userena.forms import SignupForm
from userena.forms import EditProfileForm
from Couches.models import Location
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


# Code adapted from: http://django-userena.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-add-extra-fields-to-forms
class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'),
                                 max_length=30,
                                 required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Last name'),
                                max_length=30,
                                required=True)
    latitude = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Latitude'),
                               max_length=30,
                               required=False,
                               validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'),])
    longitude = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Longitude'),
                                max_length=30,
                                required=False,
                                validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'),])

    def save(self):
        # First save the parent form and get the user.
        new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()
        new_user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        new_user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        new_user.save()

        Location.objects.create(available=True,
                                user=new_user,
                                latitude=self.cleaned_data['latitude'],
                                longitude=self.cleaned_data['longitude'])

        return new_user


class EditProfileFormExtra(EditProfileForm):
    description = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Description'),
                                  max_length=300,
                                  required=False,
                                  widget=forms.Textarea)
    contact_information = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Contact Information'),
                                          max_length=300,
                                          required=False,
                                          widget=forms.Textarea)
    graduation_year = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Graduation Year'),
                                      max_length=4,
                                      required=False,
                                      validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\d{4}$'), ])
    address = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Contact Information'),
                                          max_length=100,
                                          required=False)
    # BUG: the two fields below do not appear on the form
    latitude = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Latitude'),
                            max_length=30,
                            required=False,
                            validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'), ])
    longitude = forms.CharField(label=_(u'lon'),
                                max_length=30,
                                required=False,
                                validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'), ])

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        profile = super(EditProfileFormExtra, self).save()
        profile.description = self.cleaned_data['description']
        profile.contact_information = self.cleaned_data['contact_information']
        profile.graduation_year = self.cleaned_data['graduation_year']

        location = Location.objects.get(user = profile.user)
        if(location):
          location.latitude = self.cleaned_data['latitude']
          location.longitude = self.cleaned_data['longitude']
          location.save()

        return profile
```

This is the template that shows the form:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Account setup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content_title %}<h2>{% blocktrans with profile.user.username as username %}Account &raquo; {{ username }}{% endblocktrans %}</h2>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

Edit your very own profile.

<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <ul id="box-nav">
    <li class="first"><a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' user.username %}"><span>{% trans 'View profile' %}</span></a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="{% url 'userena_profile_edit' user.username %}">{% trans "Edit profile" %}</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'userena_password_change' user.username %}">{% trans "Change password" %}</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="{% url 'userena_email_change' user.username %}">{% trans "Change email" %}</a></li>
  </ul>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    <legend>{% trans "Edit Profile" %}</legend>
    {{ form.as_p }}
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Save changes" %}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')

    first_name = models.TextField()
    last_name = models.TextField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    contact_information = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True) # extra contact information that the user wishes to include
    graduation_year = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True) # Is this location available to couchsurf

    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=30, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'),]) # floating point validator
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=30, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'),]) # floating point validator

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This is the view from django-userena (https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/views.py)

```
Adef profile_edit(request, username, edit_profile_form=EditProfileForm,
                 template_name='userena/profile_form.html', success_url=None,
                 extra_context=None, **kwargs):
    """
Edit profile.

Edits a profile selected by the supplied username. First checks
permissions if the user is allowed to edit this profile, if denied will
show a 404. When the profile is successfully edited will redirect to
``success_url``.

:param username:
Username of the user which profile should be edited.

:param edit_profile_form:

Form that is used to edit the profile. The :func:`EditProfileForm.save`
method of this form will be called when the form
:func:`EditProfileForm.is_valid`. Defaults to :class:`EditProfileForm`
from userena.

:param template_name:
String of the template that is used to render this view. Defaults to
``userena/edit_profile_form.html``.

:param success_url:
Named URL which will be passed on to a django ``reverse`` function after
the form is successfully saved. Defaults to the ``userena_detail`` url.

:param extra_context:
Dictionary containing variables that are passed on to the
``template_name`` template. ``form`` key will always be the form used
to edit the profile, and the ``profile`` key is always the edited
profile.

**Context**

``form``
Form that is used to alter the profile.

``profile``
Instance of the ``Profile`` that is edited.

"""
    user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(),
                             username__iexact=username)

    profile = user.get_profile()

    user_initial = {'first_name': user.first_name,
                    'last_name': user.last_name}

    form = edit_profile_form(instance=profile, initial=user_initial)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = edit_profile_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile,
                                 initial=user_initial)

        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save()

            if userena_settings.USERENA_USE_MESSAGES:
                messages.success(request, _('Your profile has been updated.'),
                                 fail_silently=True)

            if success_url:
                # Send a signal that the profile has changed
                userena_signals.profile_change.send(sender=None,
                                                    user=user)
                redirect_to = success_url
            else: redirect_to = reverse('userena_profile_detail', kwargs={'username': username})
            return redirect(redirect_to)

    if not extra_context: extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['form'] = form
    extra_context['profile'] = profile
    return ExtraContextTemplateView.as_view(template_name=template_name,
                                            extra_context=extra_context)(request)
```

Comment: Let us see the template code where the form is inserted as well.

Comment: Thank you, I have just added the code for the template in the message now.

Comment: Show your model please.

Comment: I guess we need to see the view as well. Also, perhaps this code should be featured at the Code Review site in addition to Stackoverflow? There is a lot of feedback to be given besides whatever will fix the weird behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: Ok I guess I can post it to the code review site too. I am relatively new to python & django so I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a weird feature I wasn't aware of. I have added the view. Any ideas of what may be causing this bug?

Comment: I have kept experimenting with this and apparently what happens is that the last two fields don't show. Why would this be?